# java http get "request reject" but work in browser

Tags: java, json

I am trying to consume a web service. The response is "Request Rejected.The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.Your support ID is: 11127005317486483617"
 
This is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;<br/>
import java.io.IOException;<br/>
import java.io.InputStreamReader;<br/>
import java.io.StringReader;<br/>
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;<br/>
import java.net.MalformedURLException;<br/>
import java.net.URL;<br/>

import java.util.*;<br/>
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;<br/>
import java.io.FileReader;<br/>
import java.io.IOException;<br/>
import org.json.JSONArray;<br/>
import org.json.JSONException;<br/>

import java.util.Iterator;<br/>
import org.json.JSONObject;<br/>
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;<br/>
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;<br/>

public class Testapp {<br/>
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, ParseException {<br/>
        String output = "abc";<br/>
        try {<br/>
            URL url = new URL("https://peps.cnes.fr/resto/api/collections/S1/search.json?q=france&maxRecords=100&startDate=2014-12-31T05:00:00&completionDate=2014-12-31T12:00:00");<br/>
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();<br/>
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");<br/>
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");<br/>
            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {<br/>
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "<br/>
                    + conn.getResponseCode());<br/>
            }<br/>
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));<br/>
            //String output;<br/>
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");<br/>
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {<br/>
            System.out.println(output);<br/>
            }<br/>
            conn.disconnect();<br/>
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {<br/>
          e.printStackTrace();<br/>
      } catch (IOException e) {<br/>
          e.printStackTrace();<br/>
      }<br/>
    }<br/>
}<br/>
```

But,this url worked well in browser. Somebody help me?

Comment: why there are lots of {<br/>} in your code ?

Comment: Are you using a proxy ?

Comment: @kaanyılmaz: dear, <br/> is just to go to new line in this stakoverflow website.

Comment: @ortis: Maybe, I am in a university. Maybe admins setup some proxy. dost it effect to the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many web sites require a `User-Agent` header in order to work properly.
So add

```
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
```

to make this work.

Comment: Really ? That seems far away from the **Device-Independent** principle of web services

Comment: @ortis who knows why this site requires the header. Software does not always follow principles.

Comment: @wero: Hi wero, i have some problems when parsing the retured json.
In detail, I get json from "https://peps.cnes.fr/resto/api/collections/S1/search.json?q=france&maxRecords=100&startDate=2014-12-31T05:00:00&completionDate=2014-12-31T12:00:00", but I can not parse Json. Both org.json and org.json.simple libraries I used got the same NullPointerException error.

Comment: @KienBUI use Gson or Jackson libaries, or post a new question. Comments should not be used to discuss problems...